# Linux mint doesn't show all the free space available

Tags: boot, usb, storage

I installed Linux mint on my 64gb flashdrive using Rufus, with the default settings according to this guide (ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). When I boot into mint, the file manager tells me I only have 6gb of free space, but GParted tells me there is 56gb of free space on the flashdrive (imgur.com/LGi60VA). Why isn't this 56gb available for me to use? Is it reserved for the system and program installs? If so, is there a way for me to change the allocation so I can use it as a user? Sorry if there aren't enough details, quite new to this

I was told these commands would be useful but I'm not sure what they mean.

```
mint@mint ~ $ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             6075532       0   6075532   0% /dev
tmpfs            1217992    9544   1208448   1% /run
/dev/sda1       60637696 1667360  58970336   3% /cdrom
/dev/loop0       1608832 1608832         0 100% /rofs
/cow             6089944   35120   6054824   1% /
tmpfs            6089944     860   6089084   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       8      5112   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            6089944       0   6089944   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            6089944       4   6089940   1% /tmp
cgmfs                100       0       100   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs            1217992      24   1217968   1% /run/user/999
mint@mint ~ $ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL      UUID                                     MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                             
└─sda1 vfat     LINUX MINT 1EE4-0C57                            /cdrom
sr0                                                             
loop0  squashfs                                                 /rofs
mint@mint ~ $ sudo lsblk -m
NAME    SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sda    57.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda1 57.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
sr0    1024M root  cdrom b
```

Comment: clearly there's more than 50G free space. you need to post a screenshot of message from the file manager.

Answer (score 0):

This line essentially indicates that you've booted a LiveCD/LiveDVD:

```
/cow             6089944   35120   6054824   1% /
```

You have space available, it's under `/cdrom`, where `/dev/sda1` ended up being mounted.

The `6GB` free space is just a `tmpfs` overlay on top of the read-only system-bearing `squashfs`. Be careful! Whatever you write that isn't under `/cdrom` will be lost when you reboot. Why `6GB`? By default, `tmpfs` is sized to half of your RAM, so I'm guessing you have about 12GB of system memory.

Also, you might not be able to write files in `/cdrom` either if `Mint` has mounted it read-only. You should be able to remount it read-write though, assuming it is actually `vfat` as it appears to be in the partition table.

Comment: So sorry for the delayed response, I installed mint directly on the flashdrive the problem went away and I forgot I asked this. 

However, I am interested in making another bootable stick now, so I'm wondering: why does file manager display tmpfs space rather than /cdrom space? i actually met the problem while trying to sync dropbox, so does it show that my programs are installed on tmpfs? if so, how come the folders are still there after I reboot? 

Also, is this in any way related to persistence? Because i read the maximum value for persistance is 8gb, which would explain the 6gb.

Comment: Folders under `/tmp` should not be there after a reboot. Your programs are not installed on `tmpfs`.